# Fail to install Virtualbox Guest Additions

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions

I am trying to install Guest Additions in CentOS8 in virtualBox 7.0.4, and the host is win 10, but cannot succeed. I did this by the following steps:

(1) update the kernel and install dependencies by:

```
#dnf update kernal*
#dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
#yum install -y perl gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers make bzip2 xorg-x11-drivers xorg-x11-utils elfutils-libelf-devel
```

(2) Add KERN_DIR to environment by:

```
#KERN_DIR=/usr/src/kernels/`uname -r`
#export KERN_DIR
```

(3) mount the virtualbox iso

```
#mkdir /mnt/iso
#mount ~Public/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions_7.0.4.iso /mnt/iso
#cd /mnt/iso
```

(4) Install Guest Additions

```
#./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

I get the following error:

```
 Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 7.0.4 Guest Additions for Linux  100%  
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
/usr/sbin/vbox-uninstall-guest-additions: line 9: /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.4/uninstall.sh: No such file or directory
Failed to remove existing installation.  Aborting...
```

Do you have any idea of how to deal with this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: These instructions look a bit different.  .... https://linuxhint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-centos/  .... Compare and see if they help.

Comment: You may need to install these packages : `yum install -y perl gcc kernel-devel kernel-headers make bzip2 xorg-x11-drivers xorg-x11-utils elfutils-libelf-devel`.

Comment: @harrymc I have modified the yum install command, but now I get different output errors about uninstall.sh script. Please see the edited version above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Had same error as you when inadvertantly removing folder
`/opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-7.0.6/`

Quick Solution workaround as per another forum (can't remember which) was remove/rename following file:

`vmbox-uninstall-guest-additions` from `/usr/sbin directory`.

Then rerun the Guest Additions install sh, it will skip the `uninstall.sh` part and proceed to the install script as per normal.